# Fix spacing when using \dot{}

Tags: math-mode, spacing

If I type `$a \sim b$`, I get [image]. However, if I type `$a \dot{\sim} b$`, I get this [image] and the spacing is gone. Is there a way to regain latex's good spacing mechanism, i.e. add spaces if needed and avoid unnecessary spacing?

Comment: )not tested, hence a comment, not an answer.)  `\sim` is a relation, so typing `$a \mathrel{\dot{\sim}} b$ should restore the proper class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to define a new command to make `\dot{\sim}` a binary relation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\dotrel}[1]{\mathrel{\dot{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[a\sim b\]
\[a\dotrel{\sim} b\]
\[a\dot{\sim} b\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this solution be parametrized by the symbol, like `=` or `\approx`?

Comment: @user3389669: You mean for `\dot{=}` and `\dot{\approx}`? Simply wrap a `\mathrel{}` around them.

Comment: I meant something like `\dotrel{<your symbol goes here>}`, where you could insert arbitrary symbols, resulting in that symbol being printed dotted and being treated like a relation.

Comment: @user3389669: Do notice there is already a `\doteq` command

Comment: @user3389669: Yes, I slightly modified my answer

Comment: The TeXnical reason is that an Acc atom (resulting from `<math accent>{<symbol>}` (for instance `\dot{\sim}`) is then treated as an Ord atom (ordinary symbol) when the math list is transformed into a horizontal list. Enveloping the construction in `\mathrel` reestablishes the nature of the atom.

Answer (score 5):

When you do something like `\dot{\sim}`, you're creating an **Acc** atom (for accent) which, by rule, is treated the same as an **Ord** atom (ordinary, like a normal letter) when the math list is converted into typesetting commands. See Rules 12 and 16 in Appendix G of the TeXbook (pages 443 and 445).

The `amsmath` package already defines an infrastructure it uses for trying and guess the right type of the second argument to `\overset` and `\underset`, so that, say, `\overset{x}{=}` results in a **Rel** atom.

The trick is to evaluate `\binrel@` on the second argument, which will redefine `\binrel@@` to be `\mathrel`, `\mathbin` or `\mathord`.

So the definition of a “smart dot” could be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sdot}[1]{\binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\dot{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Relation: $a \sdot{\sim} b$

Relation: $a \sim b$

Operation: $a \sdot{\times} b$

Operation: $a \times b$

\end{document}
```

Note that the spacing is the same for dotted and undotted symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `a \mathrel{\dot{\sim}} b`.

[image]